# How to detect Enter key in a C WPM program?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am supposed to create a typing tutor program which is essentially similar to WPM testing for explicitly one paragraph. The idea is that the program will automatically check the result upon pressing enter, whether or not the user has finished typing the entire paragraph (i.e: ending mid-paragraph). The problem is, how do I detect the enter key or '\n' without resorting to brute coding such as using getch?

Here are the following code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

// Initializer

int x=0, y=0;
int mistake=0;
char entry [200][20];
char paragraph [200][20] = { // paragraph[0][0][0] = paragraph[WORD][LETTER]
/* 1) 92 WORDS, 579 CHARS */ "English", "students", "are", "sometimes", "taught", "that", "a", "paragraph", "should", "have", "a", "topic", "sentence", "or", "main", "idea,", "preferably", "first,", "and", "multiple", "supporting", "or", "detail", "sentences", "which", "explain", "or", "supply", "evidence.", "One", "technique", "of", "this", "type,", "intended", "for", "essay", "writing,", "is", "known", "as", "the", "Schaffer", "paragraph.", "For", "example,", "the", "following", "excerpt", "from", "Dr.", "Samuel", "Johnson's", "Lives", "of", "the", "English", "Poets,", "the", "first", "sentence", "is", "the", "main", "idea:", "that", "Joseph", "Addison", "is", "a", "skilled", "describer", "of", "life", "and", "manners.", "The", "succeeding", "sentences", "are", "details", "that", "support", "and", "explain", "the", "main", "idea", "in", "a", "specific", "way."};
int wordcount = { 92 };

// Interface

printf("Welcome to the Typing Tutor!\n");
printf("===============================================================================\n");
for (x=0;x<wordcount[0];x++) printf ("%s ", paragraph[0][x]);
printf("\n===============================================================================\n");
printf("Please type this paragraph below:\n\n");

// Input / Word Count Incrementer

for (x=0;x<wordcount[0];x++){
    scanf ("%s", &entry[x]);
    if (entry[x] == "\n") break; // Supposedly detects "enter", then breaks the loop. Doesn't seem to work.
    word++;
}

// Typo Checker

for (x=0;x<word;x++) if (strcmp(entry[x],paragraph[0][x]) != 0) mistake++;

// Output

y=wordcount[0]-word;

if (word>0) printf("You did not type %i words.\n", y);
else if (word<0) printf("You overtyped %i words.\n", y);
printf("You have made %i typoes.\n\n", mistake);
```

Comment: If you want to read line by line while detecting end of line (user presses enter), then use fgets, and use sscanf or strtok or simple for loop to get words on that line. If you want to read char by char, you have to use conio getch.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use getch() or kbhit() for recording the enter key and storing in a variable.Like for getch()
K=getch()
Kbhit()-It is a very good function for finding which key was pressed